Identify movie about a teen with supernatural powers, chased by government
I watched this as a kid in the 90s/early 00s and in style it looked like something that's been shot in the 80s. My memory is next to non-existent, but what I remember is that it was about a teen male with some kind of supernatural powers (i'm pretty sure it was telekinesis/telepathy). His powers might have been a result of some scientific experiment or wearable tech (helmet/goggles?) but I don't remember too well. I think he was also able to see the vital stats of people he's looking at in something like a HUD, but it could be my memory making up stuff.
I'm not sure if he was chased by the government but was definitely chased by some organized group. I think he was able to stop or overload the heart of one of the 'agents' that were after him. 
There is one detail from a scene that is imprinted in my mind. There was a death mask or bust of a famous composer (I think Chopin or Schumann?) hung on a wall and at one point there were 'real' tears on it.
I think the final scene was some kind of television broadcast and I remember hearing about world war 3, but i'm pretty sure it wasn't that world war 3 had begun, rather it was some kind of fictional cold war propaganda clip. 
More:

I'm not sure it was an American production or whether it was even from a English-speaking country because it was dubbed in my language, but I'd bet it was.
Real life and in color.
I watched it on cable TV.

I know this is all super random and unclear, but I've been looking for years before finally asking here.

Welcome to Movies.SE! We have a minimum requirement for ID questions on this site. Do you remember when/where/how you watched this movie? What language was it in? Was it an American production, or from a different country? Was it real life or animated? Was it in color? We'll need answers to these questions to help us track down an answer to this question.  If you have this information, please edit it into your question.

Hi. I'm not sure it was an American production or whether it was even from a english-speaking country because it was dubbed in my language, but I'd bet it was. Real life and color - yes. I watched it on cable TV.

At first I thought it looked familiar but it's not that. I'm pretty sure it wasn't a tv show, but could have been a tv movie. Also the mood was darker, and it tried to be philosophical at the end. The teared up Chopin head is the only thin I know happened for sure.

Lot of movies like that. Jumper and Push are two that come to mind.

@DustinDavis, it's certainly pre-00s though

nope, definitely not a family movie and the guy was older

I'm sorry if this is incorrect, but could it be Flight of the Navigator? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091059/
I think that meets at least some of your description, but dont remember well enough if it meets all

Hmmm. The death mask of Chopin crying is a "true" (as in those who were there, including Uri Geller, believe it) story, it seems: http://www.wqxr.org/story/108891-ten-questions-byron-janis/

@ToddWilcox, I found this as well, but has nothing to do with the film, sadly. :/

I have a few ideas, but none with a composer's crying death mask (that I know of, anyway). Are you sure it's from the same movie? And do you happen to remember the protagonist's appearance?

I'm positive it's from the same movie, that's the only detail I'm 100% sure about. I think his hairstyle was similar to this: link, and had a nerdy physique.

I'm glad that you're enthusiastic about this but we don't allow monetary offers of rewards on SE.

shut up and take my money :)
